# class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mapping

This is the error that occurs when i try to execute my spring boot api to generate the database :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at casa.net.ospc.BackEndOspcApplication.main(BackEndOspcApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne (org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue and org.hibernate.mapping.ToOne are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.BinderHelper.checkMappedByType(BinderHelper.java:1086) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.isReversePropertyInJoin(CollectionBinder.java:1571) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.noAssociationTable(CollectionBinder.java:1582) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1543) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1534) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1803) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar:6.2.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
[Class Client with an id : 'id_client'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajkhg.png)
[Class Attache with an id : 'id_attache'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hYER.png)
```

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots and add the whole stacktrace of the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Hibernate 6.2, there was a new check introduced for bidirectional mapping which was breaking if you have done one to many mapping with column name. Temporarily, use the bidirectional way. i.e. Use joincolumn annotation in child class instead of using column name for mapping. 
This issue is expected to be fixed in Hibernate 6.3

Comment: `@OneToMany
    @ToStringExclude
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(name = "Attache_Client_Association",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_attache"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_client"))
    public List<Client> clientList;`

Comment: issue ticket: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16593

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing @ManyToOne in Entity 2:

```
// In Entity 1 (Target Entity).
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "webContentFragmentGroup") 
private Set<WebContentFragment> webContentFragments = new HashSet<>(0);


// In Entity 2:
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // --> Need to add this.
@JoinColumn(name = "Web_Content_Fragment_Group_Id", nullable = false, //
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "WCFR_WCFG_FK"))
private WebContentFragmentGroup webContentFragmentGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to improper use of @OneToMany & @ManyToOne annotations.
Hibernate expects bidirectional mapping from both sides.
To fix this error you need to use both mappedBy & @JoinColumn appropriately.

Here is how i was able to fix this:

```
class Ticket{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ticket")
    private List<Payment> payments;
}
```

Ticket has One to Many relation with Payment.

```
class Payment{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Ticket ticket;
}
```

Reference:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Answer (score 0):

On my case it was the mappedBy column I was using... I pointed it to a "Long id" value white it should point to the mapped object "Cart cart" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue represent improper usage of `@OneToMany` in parent entity and `@ManyToOne` in child entity.

You might have forget to add @ManyToOne in referenced Entity causing the error.

Simple syntax of reference and reference back.

```
@OneToMany
private List<ProductAttribute>  productAttributes;
```

Reference back

```
 @ManyToOne 
 @JoinColumn(name="product_id",referencedColumnName="Product_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
 private Product product;
```

Note : Use `insertable=false,updatable=false` if using multiple references of same column

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is stuck after reading the other answers, here's the mistake that triggered this very obscur error.
I had a referenced entity with an @EmbeddedId class, and I was referencing this class through a *@OneToMany* association using `mappedBy = id.entityB`.  When I removed this *@EmbeddedId* class to use a surrogate Long id key I forgot to remove "id" from the `mappedBy` property.

**Before (with *@EmbeddedId*):**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.entityB")
private Set<EntityA> entities;
```

**After (without *@EmbeddedId*, note the absence of `id.`):**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityB")
private Set<EntityA> entities;
```